# iPhone - Should I create 2 diffrent sizes images for Retina & Not retina display dedive?

Tags: xcode, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, iphone-4

This my first time develop app's.

According the Apple iOS Human interface guidelines, it says that UIBarButtonItem image sizes are Approximately 20 x 20 & Approximately 40 x 40.

I know that 20x20 is for previous version device of iPhone4, 
and 40 x 40 is for iPhone4's Retina display.

Now I created an UIBarbuttonItem, my image size is 40x40, Setting image scale to 2.

It's runs perfectly on iPhone Simulator & iPhone4 Simulator,
both simulator's image looks clear and beautiful.

I want to ask if is right? Do I need to create an 20x20 image for iPhone3&3GS?
Or Just one size of image, 40x40, and set scale to "2.0"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create two images:

1. 20x20 with name, for example, `image.png`
2. 40x40 with name `image@2x.png`

In your code you should set that image using method `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];`. That method will automatically choose appropriate image:

1. for non-retina displays it will be `image.png`
2. for retina displays it will be `image@2x.png`

Be patient, you don't need to scale any image by yourself.

Also you can run simulator for retina displays. Just open iOS Simulator and navigate to `Hardware -> Device -> iPhone (retina)`.

Comment: Thanks, I follwed your instructions and succed, nice and simple, thank you!